# What to do when library function parameters aren't const

Tags: c++, constants

Most of my code-base is immutable; however, due to quirks of the language design, I'm unable to mark my variables `const`.

In a vast majority of cases, especially when inter-operating with C code, I find function parameters not marked const, even though they provably do not modify them.
One such example is [fts_open(...)](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-arch/2006-May/005253.html). At this point the compiler forces me to tediously remove `const` qualifiers from large parts of my code, and thereby removing the safety it offered.

One trivial solution is to compile with `-fpermissive`, but this is completely contrary to my intent.

Apart from rewriting every single C library ever written, what can I do to still get the benefits from leaning on the compiler?

i.e. this type of code does not work:

```
void function(immutable_type const &param)
{
    char const * const fts_arg[2]{std::data(param.path), nullptr};
    FTS *tree = fts_open(fts_arg, FTS_OPTIONS, nullptr);
    ...
}
```

At this point I have to:

- Remove const from the `fts_args` variable.
- Remove const from the function parameter.
- Remove const from `path` inside the datatype definition.
- Remove const from the variable being passed to `function`.
- Recursively remove `const`s from the entire call chain.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Do you know if the calls are actually really const?

Comment: If you are really sure the library doesn't modify the data, you could edit its headers you include, so that they had the necessary `const` — or make your own, C++-friendly, version of the headers.

Comment: Let's say I do. Even in the example case of fts_open() I am fairly certain.

Comment: Fairly certain may not be enough :/ There is always the option of const_casting the const away. In some cases, I modified the headers (C/Fortran code -> BLAS), in other cases, I const_casted, in others I kept the modifiable inputs, because the contract was not clear enough.

Comment: From [manual page](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/fts.3.html), they have some `const`. So I presume they are allowed to mutate non const part.

Comment: Could always pass a copy. Inefficient but it'd work.

Comment: @Ruslan, I'm not sure I'm capable of that. Would I not then run into bigger problems maintaining and distributing large parts of (let's say) GNU code? What about licences?

Comment: Apparently, the issue discussed in your link makes the only viable solution to be `const_cast`ing the parameter to the type expected by `fts_open` (or removing the offending `const` from your type). Upstream declaration is unlikely to be changed due to problem in the languages (both C and C++).

Comment: @Ruslan, isn't `const_cast`ing from `const` undefined behavior? Could the compiler then optimize the code away?

Comment: It's not `const_cast` itself which would cause UB, it's the attempt to modify the `const` object, which `fts_open` presumably avoids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what `const_cast` is for. If you absolutely know that a function won't change the pointed/referenced object, then it is OK to `const_cast` the constness of your pointer/reference away in order to pass it into that function, despite referring to a const object.

> isn't const_casting from const undefined behavior?

No. `const_cast` itself is never UB. But modifying a const object is. So if you cannot prove that a function taking a non-const pointer/reference doesn't modify the object, then it is not safe to pass the `const_cast`ed reference into that function.

Also consider whether the implementation might be changed in future to use non-constness.

---

In case where you cannot prove that the non-constly referred/pointed object won't be modified, you can make a local copy of the constly referred argument of your wrapper function. The overhead of this copy may be trivial (`int`) or non-trivial (long `std::vector`).

If you cannot prove that the object won't be modified, and copying is expensive (or not possible), then as last resort, you have to get rid of constness of your own argument (and propagate the change up the call chain). Or use another API in the implementation.